# Building HDF5 1.8.7 with Visual Studio 2010 (after CMake)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, hdf5

I used CMake to generate a Visual Studio 2010 solution for the HDF5 1.8.7 source.  I opened the HDF5.sln file in Visual Studio, did a build on the ALL_BUILD project and got a bunch on linking errors (eg. "error LNK1181: cannot open input file '....\bin\Release\hdf5dll.lib'")

The documentation in the "CMake.txt" file said I should be able to do the build from Visual Studio after the solution was created by cmake generation.  Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that the hdf5dll.dll file is being successfully built and placed in the ..\..\bin\Release folder but there is no static lib file (hdf5dll.lib)

Comment: Building with the "cmake --build . --config Release" command seems to build everything correctly...

Comment: If your problem is solved, write the solution as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: I don't believe it is solved, sorry.  I wanted to build with a working Visual Studio solution.  I found a way to build it, but the documentation said I could build with Visual Studio - I can't.

Comment: I hope that doesn't sound snarky - it wasn't meant to.  My goal starting out was to create a nice VS2010 solution for us to use.  I appreciate the help!